# Order posts by tags count?

Tags: wp-query, query, tags, order

I am trying to order posts by tag count. I want to order posts with no tags first and posts with highest count last.

I tried and got posts with no tags only.

```
    $tags = get_tags();
    $tag_ids = wp_list_pluck( $tags, 'term_id' );

    $args1 = array (
       'orderby'          => 'DEC',
       'post_type'        => 'post',
       'pagination'       => true,
       'posts_per_page'   => '1',
       'tag__not_in'      =>  $tag_ids,
       'meta_key'         => '_thumbnail_id',
    );
```

How do I order posts based on the tags count?

Comment: I don't think you can do that directly. Although you can save terms count for each post in a custom meta field (on post publish) and then in your query define sort by that meta field. Or while running your query, you can save terms count along with posts ids in another array, then sort them by count and print posts. Second one will consume more resources so I would recommend first method.

Comment: SELECT p.ID,COUNT(*) count
    FROM wp_term_relationships r, wp_posts p, wp_term_taxonomy x
    WHERE r.object_id = p.ID AND p.post_type = 'post'
        AND r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id AND x.taxonomy = 'post_tag'
    GROUP BY object_id ORDER BY count;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Robert hue says you can't do it directly, you need a filter and a `CASE` in the orderby eg

```
$args1 = array (
   'orderby'          => 'tag_count',
   'order'            => 'DESC',
   'post_type'        => 'post',
   'pagination'       => true,
   'posts_per_page'   => '1', // 1 post per page?!
   'meta_key'         => '_thumbnail_id',
   'suppress_filters' => false,
);

function wpse173949_posts_clauses( $pieces, $query ) {
    if ( $query->get( 'orderby' ) != 'tag_count' ) return $pieces;
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! ( $order = $query->get( 'order' ) ) ) $order = 'DESC';
    $pieces[ 'fields' ] .= $wpdb->prepare(
        ', (SELECT COUNT(tr.object_id) FROM ' . $wpdb->term_relationships . ' tr'
        . ' JOIN ' . $wpdb->term_taxonomy . ' AS tt ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id'
        . ' WHERE tr.object_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID AND tt.taxonomy = %s) AS tag_count'
        , 'post_tag' );
    // Treat zero tagged posts as max int (~0).
    $pieces[ 'orderby' ] = 'CASE WHEN tag_count THEN tag_count ELSE ~0 END ' . $order;
    return $pieces;
}

add_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse173949_posts_clauses', 10, 2 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args1 );
remove_filter( 'posts_clauses', 'wpse173949_posts_clauses', 10 );
```