# Order posts by taxonomy count

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy

I have created new post type (hotels) and taxonomies (localisation).

I want to loop my hotels ordering by count DESC of taxonomies. I want to sort my hotel by count of localisation (I mean order from more hotels in localisation to less hotels).

I try this :

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'hotels',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_localisation',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'orderby'    => 'count',
                'order'    => 'DESC',
                'terms'    => $localisation_child->term_id,
            ),
        ),
    );
```

Is it possible using WP_query args ?

Answer (score 1):

[this topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/173949/order-posts-by-tags-count) might help you. By default args of WP_Query - this is impossible.

> I don't think you can do that directly. Although you can save terms
> count for each post in a custom meta field (on post publish) and then
> in your query define sort by that meta field. Or while running your
> query, you can save terms count along with posts ids in another array,
> then sort them by count and print posts. Second one will consume more
> resources so I would recommend first method.
>
> SELECT p.ID,COUNT(*) count FROM wp_term_relationships r, wp_posts p,
> wp_term_taxonomy x WHERE r.object_id = p.ID AND p.post_type = 'post'
> AND r.term_taxonomy_id = x.term_taxonomy_id AND x.taxonomy =
> 'post_tag' GROUP BY object_id ORDER BY count;
>
> you can't do it directly, you need a filter and a CASE in the orderby eg

Comment: Yes I found this post, I guess it is the only way, thanks